# Reader Monad, Code Refactor, dynamically bound vars?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

### Existing Code:

See: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35ebb1485967b1e4a69adbb6272b186e

I'm writing a WebGL binding for learning purposes. (The purpose of this question is not about gamma/glsl or cljs-webgl -- it's about refactoring. WebGL is a minor detail).

### Problem

If we look at the code above, many functions take either `gl` as an argument or `gl` and `shaderProgram` as an argument. Here, `gl` is the OpenGL context and `shaderProgram` is the fragment and vertex shaders.

It's somewhat tedious to pass `gl` around all the time. In standard Haskell approach, one would use a `Reader` monad, stick `gl` in the reader monad, and be done with it.

In Clojure, the closest similar approach I can think of is:

```
(binding [*gl* ... ]) ;; and use a dynamically bound var.
```

### Question:

Are there any downsides to this approach (performance?) I should be aware of?

Are there other solutions to this approach?

Comment: Here's some solutions that include using the reader monad in Clojure: http://software-ninja-ninja.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/5-faces-of-dependency-injection-in.html

Comment: @ChrisMurphy : Nice! TIL this problem is called "dependency injection"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage is exactly what dynamic vars were created for.

I assume you've read https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding

Note that dynamic vars can also be used for return values.

You should also check out:

- https://stuartsierra.com/2013/03/29/perils-of-dynamic-scope
- https://cemerick.com/2009/11/03/be-mindful-of-clojures-binding/

You should also look at:

- http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs
- http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/alter-var-root

### UPDATE 2016-10-30

Regarding Plumatic Schema, I always set it up like so:

```
(ns xyz
  (:require ...
    [schema.core :as sk]
  ))

; Prismatic Schema type definitions
(sk/set-fn-validation! true)
```

This tells Schema to verify the types of function arguments upon function entry.

***I always use this in my test namespaces,*** and usually for my other namespaces as well (***always during development***, often later too). It is not the same as a type-checking compiler, but it is close.

Comment: Just saw https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding#example-5784550fe4b0bafd3e2a049e -- appears to have weird issues with threads / async that I was unaware of.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use a dynamic var if you don't want do.  You could use a globar var to hold the value, or a global var which is an `atom` holding the value.  Also, most programs use only a single thread (at least to start!).

Comment: One of the first "dangerous" examples from docs is: (binding [*foo* :bar]
  (js/setTimeout
    (fn []
      *foo* ;;=> nil
      )) .. it turns out I use this exact pattern in WebGL: namely (js/setInterval RENDER_FUNC 60fps). Maybe "thread" is not the right word -- but callbacks / async seems to cause problems if not careful.

Comment: If you only ever have one value for `gl` you could just hold it in a global atom `(def gl (atom {...} ))`

Comment: I got it working with binds. Basically, it needs to do something like: (let [gl *gl*] (js/setInterval (fn [] (binding [*gl* gl] .... )))) where the "let" takes the dynamic *gl*, captures it in a local "gl", then the "binding" abuses the local scope of the "gl" to re-bind *gl*. :-)

Comment: I've been trying hard to avoid globals. Tbh, I don't think I'm going to be happy until I get a haskell like type checking in clojure, so I can use reader monads (with all the type safety). :-)

Comment: I have also been missing type safety in Clojure. As a consequence, I make frequent use of Plumatic Schema https://github.com/plumatic/schema

Comment: I haven't tried schema, but I worked through 80% of the spec guide http://clojure.org/guides/spec . However, there's still things I'd like to be able to check at compile time -- for example, saying: the second argument of this function must be either :fragment-shader or :vertex-shader -- and if it's not, please tell me at compile time. :-)

Comment: That's what Schema is for.  The first time it saves you from a major problem you'll never go back.

Comment: From all the dos I've read, Schema is *runtime 'contract checking'*, not *compile type checking* -- if that's the case, (1) it won't catch this at compile time and (2) it's not clear why I would use Schema [an library] over Clojure.spec [a langauge builtin]. If my logic is wrong, please correct me.